# How to fetch one column data in python pymysql

Tags: python, pymysql

How to fetch just one column as array in python with pymysql;

for example sql:

```
select name from users
```

data:

```
["Tom", "Ben", "Jon"]
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: Like PHP: `$data = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);`

Comment: Haven't you encountered this problem? Or just use for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor = conn.cursor() # where conn is your connection
cursor.execute('select name from users')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
result_list = [row[0] for row in rows]
```

Comment: @Fredyang On Stack Overflow you don't say, "Thank you!". You *accept* the answer if you believe it is correct. You can look up how to do that if you do not know how.